# php - escape string

Tags: php, escaping, newline

I'm busy with a PHP project that has to work in different languages, so I made a system with strings that are read from files, but when I want to read a file like this:

Username/ \n password wrong

It shows the \n instead of escaping it to a newline. How can I let PHP do this?

Thans already,
DirkWillem

Comment: Can you show the code that prints that out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider using a suitable storage format instead of something you created yourself.  base64_encode(), or json_encode() would be good candidates.

But, to address your immediate problem, just use str_replace()

```
$new = str_replace('\n', "\n", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you have encapsulated the string in single quotes `'`. You have to encapsulate the string in double quotes `"` in order to make `\n` work.

Example:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/Fr4SHH

Note that i'm using the function `nl2br` to replace the `\n` to `<br />` when displaying on web pages. But you can see that in the first string the `\n` is simply printed as a string, but the `\n` does get parsed in the second string.

This is because PHP sees `\n` as some sort of variable. And variables only work in strings with double quotes.

Comment: He said its read from a file, implying not executed as php code, making quotes irrelevant.